# opening files added to a combobox

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim dir = "..//Football/"
Private Sub FTablebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FTablebutton.Click

    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        FfilesComboBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub FfilesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FfilesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim openfile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString)
    'start the process using the openfile string
    Process.Start(openfile)
End Sub
```

I am able to add all the files to combobox but the problem is i cannot open the file when selected from the combobox

Comment: you need to add the path and extension back

Comment: If you loose the extension of the files added to your combo you have no chance to reopen them. Use GetFileName(file) and when calling Process.Start use Path.Combine(dir, openFile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Then use Visual studio 2008 or newer. you can use Anonymous class to store the full file path with the `FileNameWithoutExtension`.

```
    Dim dir = "..//Football/"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        FfilesComboBox.DisplayMember = "Text"

End Sub

Private Sub FTablebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FTablebutton.Click

    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Dir)
        FfilesComboBox.Items.Add(New With {.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), .Value = file})
    Next

End Sub
```

you can use `ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value` to get the value (that is the file full path)

```
Private Sub FfilesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FfilesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

    'start the process using the openfile string
    Process.Start(FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.Value)
End Sub
```

This will work even you choose to loop over sub directories.

This code is tested and worked fine

Comment: I tried now getting this error on the code line  Process.Start(FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.Value)                                  error is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll"

Comment: What is the path you are trying to execute. The exception is not from the code provided.

Comment: "ASPTS\bin\x64\Football\"  ASPTS is the name of my project and inside x64 folder i have added Football folder

Comment: Finally figured out what was wrong; i used this line of code  "process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.Value)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Sub FTablebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FTablebutton.Click

    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        FfilesComboBox.DisplayMember = "key"
        FfilesComboBox.ValueMember = "value"
        FfilesComboBox.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub FfilesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FfilesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim openfile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.Value.ToString)
    'start the process using the openfile string
    Process.Start(openfile)
End Sub
```